# Convert multiple files into PDF

Tags: java, apache-poi, itext, file-extension

My questions is rather theoretical. I need to implement an application that takes different file extensions such as **[asp,bmp,doc,docx,html,jpg,pdf,pdf,png,pptx,sql,txt,xls,xlsx]** and converts them all into a consecutive PDF file for print. 
I did my research in terms of coding and found multiple libraries that do the job 
such as **Apache POI, iText, aspose.pdf.jar** and others I tested them out on individual portions of the idea. They work great but require a lot of women-hours to implement the desired application. My question is, is there anything more complete that will speed up the job. For example a library such as apache POI that does not require specifying every single padding and background color.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Would you be willing to use services/programs offered by the underlying operating system? And if you would, what is the operating system your application is supposed to work on? If your application is required to run only one kind of an operating system, e.g. Windows or some brand of GNU/Linux, then you might get out of the trouble easier by simply using something like PDFWriter on Windows or OpenOffice PDF printing (to file) on GNU/Linux.

Comment: @SamiLaine Thanx for your comment. I only need to support Windows. However, the clients that's going to be using it are dummy and they need it as easy as possible. I am currently exploring the PDFWriter that you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge and experience not a single API is present there who provide all solution without this. Because of that we need to use Apache POI, iText, aspose.pdf.jar , FOP.

In java(using jquery as per my knowledge) you are able take snapshot of rendered page using stream which you will need to proceed at serverside and generate PDF which generate pdf file same like html page without any extra formatting but it having limitation that you can't use landscape. If page data is big then it shrinks pdf which causes small font(in very large page even you unable to read pdf).